# Do we need a [forward-slash]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Today I came across the tag [forward-slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forward-slash). It seems fairly pointless to me, as it's used on several unrelated questions that simply involve some use of the `/` symbol, e.g.:

- [Are unnecessary slashes in a URL bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659504/are-unnecessary-slashes-in-a-url-bad)
- [Lost use of forward slash in windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199792/lost-use-of-forward-slash-in-windows-command-prompt)
- [How do I create and append an image with Javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051437/how-do-i-create-and-append-an-image-with-javascript-jquery)

I'd say that having a tag for the `/` symbol doesn't add any useful information to the question - for example, we wouldn't have a [question-mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question-mark) tag for questions involving query strings and ternary operators.

Some stats:

- We currently have 58 questions tagged as [forward-slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forward-slash).
- It has no tag wiki.
- It has no followers.
- Of the 58 questions, all have other tags that are more useful in describing the question.
- 55 of the 58 questions are rated 0 or above.

Comment: Move [forward-slash] I can't see around your top hat!

Comment: @Trobbins nice!

Comment: @Trobbins Huh? Surely you already thought of "Slash the [forward-slash]"?

Comment: @ThisSuit depends on which way he's facing. I may be seeing a backslash!

Comment: @Trobbins No, that's a different burninate request: "[backslash] backlash" ;P Seriously though, maybe [tag:backslash] should be added here, I don't see a material difference from [tag:forward-slash].

Comment: Tag also has no followers.  Can't believe there are no experts on `/`.

Comment: While you're at it, can you get rid of [tag:trailing-character] too?

Comment: Going forward, I think we should slash tags like this.

Comment: Looks like we can bundle [slash], [backslash], [forward-slash], and [trailing-slash] in this post.

Comment: @Trobbins [Slash] and burn.

Comment: [tag:trailing-character] has 44 questions; [tag:trailing-slash] has 117 questions.  Ouch!

Comment: “Burninate tagged[forward-slash]forward-slash”?

Comment: There is now a severe shortage of people traipsing around after other people — or, at least, there's no question still tagged [tag:trailing-character] any more.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We currently have zero questions with [forward-slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forward-slash).  With the passage of a little time, it will vanish in the dustbin of history.

[image: ***TROGDOR***]

There are fewer questions with [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash) (446 questions) and [slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slash) (266 questions) too.  I suspect both of those should be cleaned up.