# Let's [slash] and burn this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I recently came across to the [slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slash) tag which has 369 questions at the time of writing. I just saw its description (emphasis mine):

> **Please do not use this tag**. The / character ("forward slash", or just "slash") is a directory separator in URLs and in many operating systems including Linux (Windows uses \ (backslash) but many applications and APIs also accept /). It is also the division operator in many languages, and marks closing tags in XML/HTML. In some languages, / characters delimit regular expressions.

and decided that it is completely useless.

Burnination criteria:

> 1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No. This is a little bit similar to [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) which is being burninated now. This depends heavily on the language used and sometimes the tag is used just because the question contains `/`.

> 2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Questions about slashes themselves aren't on-topic here — although I haven't found any question about slashes themselves.

> 3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

No. Questions about the use of slashes in a language are about the language and [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) of it. With other words, questions about the use of semicolons in x, should be tagged [x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x) and if x = language, questions should be tagged also with [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax).

> 4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No. As mentioned, the meaning differs. Language must be specified.

This has been proposed earlier for the same symbol, different named where it was mentioned that [*slash]es tags should also be burninated. See it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305689).

Comment: Related: the [tag:pod] wiki excerpt also starts with a *do-not-use* disclaimer, which has sparked a lot of confusion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36676) and [there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262736)

Comment: Note that the [tag:comma], [tag:colon], [tag:backslash], [tag:caret], [tag:dollar-sign], [tag:ampersand], [tag:parentheses] tags are lurking in the wings, awaiting their turn for burnination.  I suspect [tag:double-quotes] and [tag:single-quotes] and maybe [tag:quotes] are also burninatable.  Maybe [tag:braces] and [tag:curly-braces] and [tag:curly-brackets] (these two don't appear to be synonyms) and [tag:square-bracket] too. The sets of questions with the tags [tag:right-angle-bracket], [tag:underscore] and [tag:double-underscore] are small enough that formal burnination isn't really needed.

Comment: Cant we merge the hell out of all those into special characters or smth?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Looks like [tag:underscore] has more than 5k questions. Seems like a bit large for not burninating. (N.B. The tag is synonymised to [tag:underscore.js] though, and doesn't seem to say anything about the `_` character. It's on a whole different league compared to those other tags.)

Comment: Typo on my part.  The tag I meant was [tag:underscores], plural — referring to a character and not the JS.  I’d seen the [tag:underscore.js] tag and that’s fine. I’d not noticed the synonym.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the [tag:underscores] tag was cleaned up some time ago and the burninate request was declined.

Comment: Then the request for burninating [tag:underscores] should be revisited, IMO.  I don't think that it was was a good decision to retain it.  It doesn't add anything to the question: the question titles refer to underscores so there's no searchability benefit to it.